# How to match specific elements that user enters with database? -php/mysql/ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, validation

I have a database of users. Each user has to enter during registration a street address, state, city, zipcode.

I also have in my database tables for States, Cities, Counties, Zipcodes. These tables are filled with all the US states, counties, cities and zipcodes available.

```
-Zipcodes are linked to cities only. 
-Cities are linked to counties and states. Each city has unique city_id
-Counties are linked to states only. Each county has unique county_id
-Each state has unique state_id
```

My PHP page specifically for addresses consists of:

```
-SELECT for States (state_name as text; state_id as value)
-TEXTBOX for City (with only city_name as value)
-TEXTBOX for Zipcode
```

I use PHP Session to store values entered by user, in case of failed form validation.

When the user submits I want to be able to put in the database the city_id (since that id will also contain county_id and state_id). But what the user submits is a city_name.
How can I match that?

Do i need a search in the database on the form validation and see if I can find the city based on what the user entered? I suppose I would need a perfect match.

Use autocomplete and retrieve with jquery and ajax cities (including the city_id) based on what the user types and then store somewhere the city_id value?

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your query to get `city_id` based on either `city_name` or `zipcode` might look like this

```sql
SELECT c.city_id 
  FROM cities c JOIN zipcodes z
    ON c.city_id = z.city_id
 WHERE c.city_name = 'Baltimore' 
    OR z.zipcode = '21201'
 GROUP BY c.city_id
```

**UPDATE** To get `city_id` by one of its zipcodes

```sql
SELECT city_id 
  FROM zipcodes
 WHERE zipcode = '21201'
 GROUP BY city_id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/755b6/2)** demo

Comment: @Cristian Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: It did help but I'd use some more help. Basically I just want to make sure that when I do that search for the city_name with the specified zipcode, I should be able to get only that city_id and make sure it is the right one. Is there anything else I can do except for this to make it better?

Comment: @Cristian See updated answer. If it was what you were looking for please, consider to **[upvote/accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.